# How to detect in perl if the client is using a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl, cgi

I'm using a CGI script to generate a dynamic webpage. I want the page to load elements differently depending on whether or not the user is using a phone (such as a blackberry) to access the website or a normal browser. Is there an environment detail I can grab to make this decision? What would be the best method of doing this (even if its using javascript and not CGI.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the Perl variable `$ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'}` and the [HTTP::BrowserDetect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aBrowserDetect) module.

Once you have the determined what browser the client is using (e.g. is it a mobile browser) - then you can make the decision on what to send back to the client (mobile version or desktop version etc)

Comment: You'll probably want to use the [mobile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::BrowserDetect#mobile()) method of HTTP::BrowserDetect.